# R for Windows front-end appears to be crashing. No errors - R just hangs and never completes calculation

Tags: r, windows

Specks on the computer:

R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14) -- "Very, Very Secure Dishes"
Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

RStudio Version 0.99.484 – © 2009-2015 RStudio, Inc.

On Windows 7, 64-bit, 16GB RAM

Code that crashes:

```
require("ggplot2") ## contains diamonds dataset  
require("caret") # contains function preprocess  
require("Rlof") # package I am using  

intvl <- 5  
krange <- seq(5, 50, intvl)  
data(diamonds)  
diamonds2 <- diamonds[,-c(2,3,4)]  
flds <- createFolds(1:nrow(diamonds2), k = 10, list = TRUE, returnTrain = FALSE)  
names(flds)[1] <- "set1";  
diamonds2.set1  <- diamonds2[flds$set1,  ]  
diamonds.lof1  <- lof(diamonds2.set1,  k = krange, cores = 2)
```

Results of code:

[image: Screenshot of code results]

Then it hangs here. I can stop R and continue but it hangs here each time. It appears that R for Windows front-end is crashing - my computer is not using any CPU for a calculation after a few seconds. This code worked a few months ago, so I'm not sure what changed.

Comment: Firewall wouldn't let me put up a screenshot - but you can run the code. After it gets to the last line - it just hangs.

Comment: Firewall is probably the keyword. I ran your code snippet on my PC with Windows 10, 64-bit, 8 GB RAM. When executing the last line, a pop-up window  appeared asking for permission as not all required features were enabled. It might be that on your system for some reason the pop-window is hidden and waiting for your action which appears as if R is hanging (no CPU usage)? Package `Rlof` tries to use multiple CPUs for the parallel implementation of Local Outlier Factor(LOF). This may require some interaction / permissions from the operating system.

Comment: Uwe Block - Thank you!  I will work with IT to solve this as It is an on again off again problem.